# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: Using join to create parent/child relationship in same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to create a parent/child relationship association in rails, and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I have two tables, products, and products_products.  These two tables allow me to have products and sub products.

```
products
-----------
id  |  title  |  ...

products_products
-----------------
id  |  product_id  |  parent_product_id  | ...
```

What I want to be able to do is get all the child products of a product.

So I have:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :products_products
    has_many :child_products, through: :products_products, source: :product
    has_many :parent_products, through: :products_products, source: :parent_product
    ...
end

class ProductsProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :parent_product, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "parent_product_id"
    ....
end
```

The parent_products association works, but I'm not sure how to get the child_products.

The SQL would be:

```
SELECT "products".*
FROM "products"
INNER JOIN "products_products" ON "products"."id" = "products_products"."product_id"
WHERE "products_products"."parent_product_id" = <myProductd>
```

The goal would be to be able to say myProduct.child_products to get a list of child products.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish from a business logic standpoint.  Right off the bat though I would say that product_products is a terrible name for a table.  I am also missing where you are defining the tables for parent_products and child_products.  can you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a self referential join, so that a product can have sub-products.  i.e. product #1 can be a parent to product #2, product #3, etc.  Any product can be any other product's parent.  I need a way to get a list of all of a product's children, or all parents of a product.

The products_products table is just the join table that holds these relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Self-Referential Association.

Change app/models/product.rb to:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_mappings
  has_many :child_products, :through => :product_mappings
  has_many :inverse_product_mappings, :class_name => "ProductMapping", :foreign_key => "child_product_id"
  has_many :inverse_child_products, :through => :inverse_product_mappings, :source => :product
end
```

and app/model/product_mapping.rb:

```
class ProductMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has product_id, child_product_id
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :child_product, :class_name => "Product"
end
```

Go ahead, try it:

```
product = Product.find 1
product.child_products
```

For more information there's a great screencast on [Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) by Ryan bates.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to keep the table structure and class names as is because it's a legacy db/app, but you pointed me in the right direction.